# INS-30014 Unable to check whether the location specified is on CFS

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Error message [INS-30014] Unable to check whether the location specified is on CFS
Installing Oracle 19c on Windows 10 pro v20H2 laptop

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting. Found out what the issue was..
I needed to set myself as the owner of the of the home folder.
I also had to navigate to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections and disable my network adapter. (I was on a dell d6000 docking station)
Then restart the install again.